# BB10 - Cascades Application - Console/Terminal Application

Tags: blackberry, console, blackberry-10, ncurses, blackberry-cascades

I am attempting to create a simple terminal application that runs on a BB10 device/simulator. I have gone through all of the available demo/example applications:

http://developer.blackberry.com/native/

I can't seem to find a way to have an application run as a console/terminal/tty-interface on the BB10 device I'm developing for. I was hoping to port some simple console games (ie: maybe a simple thing like "Hunt the Wumpus", http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hunt_the_Wumpus), and then maybe take a crack at a Rogue or Nethack port as well (hopefully without having to depend on the ncurses library (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses), but it's OK if I have to rely on ncurses. It just saves me from having to write additional interfacing code).

Can someone please provide a short, simple example of what I would need to write in a basic BB10 application that opens a black-and-white terminal with color support? It can be short, and just something I have to paste into an empty project.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

https://github.com/blackberry/NDK-Samples/tree/master/HelloWorldDisplay

It's listed near the bottom.